# Heroku showing error while deploying ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

-----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby

-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.3

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7

```
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........

   Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...

   Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

   Fetching git://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass.git

   Using i18n 0.7.0

   Using rake 10.4.2

   Using json 1.8.3

   Using thread_safe 0.3.5

   Using builder 3.2.2

   Using erubis 2.7.0

   Using mini_portile 0.6.2

   Using rack 1.6.4

   Using mime-types 2.6.1

   Installing arel 6.0.2

   Installing minitest 5.7.0

   Installing execjs 2.5.2

   Using thor 0.19.1

   Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1

   Using tilt 1.4.1

   Using multi_json 1.11.2

   Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0

   Installing nested_form 0.3.2

   Using bundler 1.9.7

   Installing bcrypt 3.1.10

   Installing remotipart 1.2.1

   Using sass 3.4.16

   Using rdoc 4.2.0

   Installing safe_yaml 1.0.4

   Installing temple 0.7.6

   Using tzinfo 1.2.2

   Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2

   Using rack-test 0.6.3

   Installing switch_user 1.1.0

   Installing warden 1.2.3

   Using mail 2.6.3

   Installing sprockets 3.2.0

   Installing uglifier 2.7.1

   Installing coffee-script 2.4.1

   Installing haml 4.0.6

   Using sdoc 0.4.1

   Installing slim 3.0.6

   Installing activesupport 4.2.1

   Installing loofah 2.0.2

   Installing rack-pjax 0.8.0

   Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3

   Installing globalid 0.3.5

   Installing activemodel 4.2.1

   Installing jbuilder 2.3.1

   Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2

   Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.6

   Installing activejob 4.2.1

   Installing activerecord 4.2.1

   Installing carrierwave 0.10.0

   Installing actionview 4.2.1

   Installing actionpack 4.2.1

   Installing actionmailer 4.2.1

   Using semantic-ui-sass 2.0.7.0 from git://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass.git (at master)

   Installing pg 0.18.2

   Using sprockets-rails 2.3.2

   Installing railties 4.2.1

   Installing kaminari 0.16.3

   Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0

   Installing responders 2.1.0

   Installing jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5

   Installing font-awesome-rails 4.4.0.0

   Using sass-rails 5.0.3

   Installing jquery-rails 4.0.4

   Installing turbolinks 2.5.3

   Installing devise 3.5.2

   Installing rails 4.2.1

   Installing rails_admin 0.7.0

   Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 67 gems now installed.

   Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.

   Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.

   Post-install message from haml:

   HEADS UP! Haml 4.0 has many improvements, but also has changes that may break

   your application:

   * Support for Ruby 1.8.6 dropped

   * Support for Rails 2 dropped

   * Sass filter now always outputs <style> tags

   * Data attributes are now hyphenated, not underscored

   * html2haml utility moved to the html2haml gem

   * Textile and Maruku filters moved to the haml-contrib gem

   For more info see:

   http://rubydoc.info/github/haml/haml/file/CHANGELOG.md

   Bundle completed (17.90s)

   Cleaning up the bundler cache.

   Removing rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)

   Removing railties (4.2.3)

   Removing globalid (0.3.6)

   Removing turbolinks (2.5.2)

   Removing rdoc (4.1.2)

   Removing pg (0.17.1)

   Removing jquery-rails (3.1.2)

   Removing minitest (5.8.0)

   Removing coffee-script-source (1.8.0)

   Removing coffee-rails (4.0.1)

   Removing uglifier (2.5.3)

   Removing activerecord (4.2.3)

   Removing puma (2.9.1)

   Removing activesupport (4.2.3)

   Removing rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)

   Removing loofah (2.0.3)

   Removing jbuilder (2.2.5)

   Removing sprockets (3.3.2)

   Removing actionpack (4.2.3)

   Removing rails_12factor (0.0.3)

   Removing arel (6.0.3)

   Removing actionmailer (4.2.3)

   Removing rails (4.2.3)

   Removing activejob (4.2.3)

   Removing rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)

   Removing execjs (2.2.2)

   Removing activemodel (4.2.3)

   Removing actionview (4.2.3)

   Removing coffee-script (2.3.0)
```

-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile

   rake aborted!

   Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'semantic-ui/modules/accordion.js' with type 'application/javascript'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/app/assets/javascripts/semantic-ui.js:1

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:64:in `resolve!'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:399:in `resolve'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:207:in `process_require_directive'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:180:in `block in process_directives'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `each'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:70:in `find_all_linked_assets'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'

   /tmp/build_d0907af71bbccdf70fa56e0562ea81f4/Bilal1122-Final-Year-Project-23d7d88/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'

   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

    !

     !     Precompiling assets failed.

     !

     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

       The Error is this:

    Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'semantic-ui/modules   /accordion.js' with type 'application/javascript'

      but i have the file name in 
      like this:
      //= require semantic-ui/modules/accordion.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Your asset precompiler can't find semantic-ui/modules/accordion.js

First make sure it exists under **app/assets/javascripts** or, better yet, **vendor/assets/javascripts**

Then, open up **config/initializers/assets.rb** and add the following:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(semantic-ui/modules/accordion.js)
```